# Save button not disabling and enabling correctly

Tags: javascript, html

My code is supposed to enable/ disable the save button based on whether or not the user has inputted a value into the input box. It is disabling, but it stays disabled even after I input a value. How do I fix this?

Here is my codes

```js
const username = document.getElementById("username");
const saveScoreBtn = document.getElementById("saveScoreBtn");
username.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  saveScoreBtn.disabled = !username.Value;
});

saveHighScore = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="  Initials">

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="saveScoreBtn" onclick="saveHighScore(event)" disabled>
                Save Score
            </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think this will work if  your value is in small letter
 saveScoreBtn.disabled = !username.Value; 

saveScoreBtn.disabled = !username.value;

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with how you're validating the text input.

Additionally, you can use the `input` event listener to ensure that regardless of how the input changes that you will get the intended result.

Here's a solution you want:

```js
username.addEventListener('input', () => {
   saveScoreBtn.disabled = username.value.length === 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple typo. `Value` should be lowercase `value`. Your code works now.

Comment: No problem. Typos are hard to catch!

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the `disabled` attribute while the is `keyup` event

```js
const username = document.getElementById("username");
const saveScoreBtn = document.getElementById("saveScoreBtn");
username.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  saveScoreBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
});

saveHighScore = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="  Initials">

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="saveScoreBtn" onclick="saveHighScore(event)" disabled>Save Score</button>
</form>
```

but what if the key is like `ctrl` or `space` also the function will run so I recommend you to use the second way

```js
const username = document.getElementById("username");
const saveScoreBtn = document.getElementById("saveScoreBtn");
username.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  if (username.value.length > 0) {
    saveScoreBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else { 
    saveScoreBtn.setAttribute('disabled', '');
   }
});
saveHighScore = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="  Initials">

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="saveScoreBtn" onclick="saveHighScore(event)" disabled>Save Score</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Here remove the disable property

```js
const username = document.getElementById("username");
const saveScoreBtn = document.getElementById("saveScoreBtn");

username.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  saveScoreBtn.disabled = event.target.value.lenght > 0;
});

saveHighScore = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="  Initials">

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="saveScoreBtn" onclick="saveHighScore(event)">
                Save Score
            </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the solution is this:

```js
var saveScoreBtn = document.getElementById("saveScoreBtn");
var control = () => {
  var username = document.getElementById("username");
  if (username.value != '') saveScoreBtn.disabled = false;
  else saveScoreBtn.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onkeyup="control()" placeholder="  Initials">
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="saveScoreBtn" onclick="saveHighScore(event)" disabled>
   Save Score
   </button>
</form>
```